# For Android pushnotification using GCM and using wamp server as local server testing on emulator only

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I'm experimenting with Android push notifications, and I want to build an example server on my own locally for testing. I am using a WAMP server, and am writing it by following the instructions in [this article](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/).

However, I keep getting this message in the emulator: "Could Not register Device on Demo Server after 5 attempts."

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because of the following ,

At the time of sending the push notification to the device you have to first send the **sender_id** and **application_id** to the GCM Server and GCM will send an **registration_id** to the device.

So the problem is within to send the sender_id and application_id or the emulator cannot find these id's..If you look into this you will solve your problem.

Thanks..hope this will helps you.